# Cant merge two queries with different columns

Tags: sql

I'm studying SQL and somehow I'm stuck with a question. I have 2 tables ('users' and 'follows').

Follows Table

| user_id | follows | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1993-09-01 |
| 2 | 1 | 1989-01-01 |
| 3 | 1 | 1993-07-01 |
| 2 | 3 | 1994-10-10 |
| 3 | 2 | 1995-03-01 |
| 4 | 2 | 1988-08-08 |
| 4 | 1 | 1988-08-08 |
| 1 | 4 | 1994-04-02 |
| 1 | 5 | 2000-01-01 |
| 5 | 1 | 2000-01-02 |
| 5 | 6 | 1986-01-10 |
| 7 | 1 | 1990-02-02 |
| 1 | 7 | 1996-10-01 |
| 1 | 8 | 1993-09-03 |
| 8 | 1 | 1995-09-01 |
| 8 | 9 | 1995-09-01 |
| 9 | 8 | 1996-01-10 |
| 7 | 8 | 1993-09-01 |
| 3 | 9 | 1996-05-30 |
| 4 | 9 | 1996-05-30 |

Users Table

| user_id | first_name | last_name | school |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Harry | Potter | Gryffindor |
| 2 | Ron | Wesley | Gryffindor |
| 3 | Hermonie | Granger | Gryffindor |
| 4 | Ginny | Weasley | Gryffindor |
| 5 | Draco | Malfoy | Slytherin |
| 6 | Tom | Riddle | Slytherin |
| 7 | Luna | Lovegood | Ravenclaw |
| 8 | Cho | Chang | Ravenclaw |
| 9 | Cedric | Diggory | Hufflepuff |

I need to list all rows from follows where someone from one house follows someone from a different house. I tried to make 2 queries, one to get all houses related to follows.user_id and another one with all houses related to follows.follows and "merge" then:

```
select a.nome_id, a.user_id_house, b.follows_id, b.follows_house 
from ( select follows.user_id as nome_id
              , users.house as user_id_house
       from   follows inner join users 
                 ON users.user_id = follows.user_id
     ) as a,
     ( select follows.follows as follows_id
             , users.house as follows_house
       from  follows inner join users 
                 ON follows.user_id = users.user_id
     ) as b
where a.user_id_house <> b.follows_house;
```

The problem is that the result is like 400 rows, its not right. I have no idea how I could solve this.

Comment: Which version (MySQL, SQL server, PostgreSQL, Oracle etc.) of SQL are you using? Please tag your question appropriately

Comment: Please add related RDBMS . Also "someone from one house and someone from a different house" bit unclear.

Comment: `the result is like 400 rows` That's because there's no relationship between `a` and `b` in your query. So you're actually doing a [CROSS JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join), i.e. Creating a cartesian product, which is obviously not the result you want.

Comment: On a side note: Be strict and consistent in your naming. It may help you later when queries get more complex. `follows` is a verb. It doesn't sound like it would reference a user. P. Kirill makes an attempt on guessing who follows who in their answer and I suppose they got it backwards. A consistent naming could be `follower_user_id` and `followed_user_id` and `following_since_date`.

Comment: Along those lines the sample data headers mention "school" while the description uses the term "house". I assume they're the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT follows.user_id, users.school, followers.user_id, followers.school FROM follows 
JOIN users ON follows.user_id=users.user_id
JOIN users as followers ON follows.follows=followers.user_id 
WHERE users.school <> followers.school
```

*Note: Pay attention to naming in my answer*

Thanks for correcting to Thorsten Kettner

Comment: Why do you outer join the users table? Do you expect to find entries without users? And even if so, your where clause would dismiss them anyway.

Comment: On a side note: You probably got it backwards, and `user_id` is the follower, and `follows` is the followed person. I made a remark in the request comments to tell the OP that their column naming is a bit confusing and should be amended.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner i do this to get each other shcools.
P.S Yeah, ive noticed my typo in naming. I should have mentioned that in my answer tho.

Comment: I am referring to you using `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`, but all you really want is an `[INNER] JOIN`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Oh, i got it. Thank you for correcting me